# Shouldn't mod_rewrite unescape URLs before mapping them when using the flag NE?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using a RewriteCond Directive to check QUERY_STRING for a matching key, if they match I redirect the user from the current page to other site discarding the QUERY_STRING at the end.

So a request to: www.mysite.com/**something.jsp?Mw%3D%3D&Tm90YXMgZGUgcHJlbnNh**

Should be redirected to: **http://othersite.com/something**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond \/something\.jsp%{QUERY_STRING} Mw%3D%3D&Tm90YXMgZGUgcHJlbnNh
RewriteRule .$ %{ENV:SCHEME}://othersite.com/something? [R=301,L,NE]
```

When I make the request however, I get redirected to:

http://othersite.com/something?Mw%253D%253D&Tm90YXMgZGUgcHJlbnNh

It seems mod_rewirte is escaping the "%" in the url to "%25".

Comment: Why use NE if you are discarding the query-string anyway. Removing the NE flag will probably solve it (too).

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the flags are stated matters, the solution consisted in changin the order of the flags to: [R=301,NE,L]

The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

duh!